# Nokia 8 combo jack headset volume bug

Tags: headphone-jack, nokia-8

My phone is a Nokia 8 with the latest update (Android Pie). I use to listen music/videos with wired headphones with some remote control buttons and a microphone. The buttons are not designed for Android phones so only the main pause/play button is working.

My phone recognizes these combo jack headphones very strangely. Once I plug the jack in, there is temporary state when the sound is correctly played for about 1 sec. Then the media is paused like if the jack is removed. Finally, when I unpause the media, the sound is played again but with different volume settings.
My guess is the phone is switching between combo mic and normal stereo headphones. This is not happenning with headphones without microphone.

My main problem is that the minimum volume in combo settings in the Android scale has continuously raised over time. Now even the first step results in a sound too loud for a quiet environment, which makes my headphones unusable. I have the impression that the volume rises every time I use the remote pause button, but that's very uncertain.

I tried many apps to reduce volume or force my phone to recognize my headphones as only stereo. I also investigated the android normal and developper settings. And the Nokia 8 is unrootable...

Any idea about how to solve this strange behaviour from Android ?
Thanks